# How to display new Window with specific values from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am writing program that is going to help me at work. This part of code is responsible for showing new window with ticket id when there is a "YES" in Warn Owner. Code works fine, yet it only shows first ID from array "found". How I can make it display all stuff?

I Tried this one with .filter yet I was unable to make it work.

```
if(!isInited) {
    ownerNotifyBaseArray = data.map((value) => ({
        id: value[dataTicketID],
        owner: value[dataWarnOwner],
        company: value[dataCompanyName]
    }));
} else {
    const newOwnerNotifyBaseArray = data.map((value) => ({
        id: value[dataTicketID],
        owner: value[dataWarnOwner],
        company: value[dataCompanyName]
    }));
    const differences = 
_.differenceWith(newOwnerNotifyBaseArray,ownerNotifyBaseArray,_.isEqual)


console.log('differences', differences)
var found = differences.find(z => z.owner === 'Yes');
if(found) {
newWindow = window.open("", "WarnOwner", "width=600,height=200");

newWindow.document.write('<p>Hey! You have a new warn owner on: <b>'+ 
(found.id)+'</b> for '+(found.company)+'</p>');
     newWindow.focus()
    //})
    ownerNotifyBaseArray = newOwnerNotifyBaseArray
}


    ownerNotifyBaseArray = newOwnerNotifyBaseArray
}
```

New window should contain all entries in array found

Comment: Look at the result of `console.log('differences', differences)`. That's an array, right? Now, add a `console.log` for `found`. What does it give you?

Comment: I think you want [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead of Array.find.  The find() method returns the value of the *first element* in the array that satisfies the provided testing function.

Comment: Ok I see it, differences aray got lengt 2 when found only 1

Comment: when I put filter, it is giving me a new window when there is nothing in array

Comment: so just to clarify when I added console.log(found) it gave me only first thing that matches from differences. When instead of find I put .filter it is running function when there is nothing there

Comment: Okay, assuming you wanted to open a new window for _every_ item in `differences`, no matter if `owner === 'Yes'`, how would you do that?

Comment: What I want to do is open a new window when there is Yes in owner. And then write this:
`newWindow.document.write('<p>Hey! You have a new warn owner on: <b>'+(found.id)+'</b> for '+(found.company)+'</p>');` 
But I need to do for all items. So if there is 3x Yes there should be one window with text informing about 3 separate IDs

Comment: I got that and I'm trying to guide you towards discovering the answer on your own ;) So: if you wanted to open a new window for each item in `differences`, how would you do that?

Comment: I believe that i need to open window first, and then write this one for each item.

Comment: Perfect. Now, `array.filter()` will return a new `array`, containing only elements that passed the check. So what you want to do is: (1) check if the filtered `array` contains items (2) if it does, open a window and (3) for every item in the filtered array, `document.write()` the data.

Comment: ok so if array is equal or longer than 1, run function. So I believe there need to be something like that `found.forEach(newWindow.document.write('<p>Hey! You have a new warn owner on: <b>'+(found.id)+'</b> for '+(found.company)+'</p>'))`

Comment: now I can see that there is nothing in "found" array after I am filtering it. When I was using find, it was putting this one object to an array, filter seems not to work for some reason